# How can I split a string using the number of characters from the beginning of the string?

Tags: c#, string, split

How can I split a string using the number of characters from the beginning of the string?

Here is my code:

```
string website;

if (message.Contains("!help"))
{
    SendChatMessage("\n!resolve <url> - Resolve a website URL\n!spam <steamID> <message> - Spam a steam user\n!help - View commands list");
}
else if (message.Contains("!resolve"))
{
    website = message;
    SendChatMessage(website);
    SendChatMessage("Resolving...");
    SendChatMessage("I couldn't resolve that IP address! Sorry!");
}
```

It's messy and formatted badly granted, but I am new to C# and I was wondering if there is any way I can split the website string using the knowledge that the initial 8 characters will be: "!resolve" After this there will be a website url.

Comment: You can do this with [`message.Substring(8)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) - that gets you everything starting at the index 8 (i.e, the 9th character).

Comment: You may want to use `message.StartsWith("!resolve")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) is the quickest and easiest way.

```
var text = "!resolve http://www.google.com";
var url = text.Substring(8).Trim();
```

The first parameter of Substring is the zero-based index into the string you want to start copying from. If you only specify that parameter, it will copy all of the text in the string starting from that index into a new string.

Comment: Thanks you fixed it! Much appreciated. I don't even understand fully what is going on there, does anyone have a resource where I can learn the substring function? Sam's reply using the microsoft resource is very hard to read (lol) with a lot of technical jargon. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Split is based on characters or strings. If you want to split on position, you want substring: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

dotnetperls has a more user-friendly explanation:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring